# How to handle RTF / doc file in Word add-in

Tags: office-js, rtf, office-addins, doc, word-addins

So I am developing Word API add-in. If I open RTF or doc file, Word is in Compatibility Mode and cannot run the addin.

In the Insert Tab, "Get Add-ins" and "My Add-ins" are not available to click, as the Word is in Compatibility Mode. So I can edit the text in this rtf file, but I cannot use my addin.

It works fine if it's docx file.

Is there any chance to open rtf / doc file in Word in such a way to make addin available? Or to make changes in my addin to run it regardless on file format?

[Addin not available to run in Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlETb.png)

Thanks!!!

Comment: RTF files are much simpler than DOC files.it has limited features. many APIs could not be run. so "Get Add-ins" and "My Add-ins" are not available, which shows that RTF format is not supported

Comment: Under the covers, the APIs need to use the docx format and what they create often needs to be saved back to that format. Use SaveAs to save these files to docx, first.